# Не отображает шрифт, добавленный через @font-face

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты

Просмотрел аналогичные вопросы и ни в одном не нашел ответа. Добавил на сайт шрифт. В базовый css-файл добавил код из font-kit с учетом моей структуры:

```css
../src/
├── apps
├── base
├── common
│   ├── font
│   │   └── open-sans
│   │       └── font.ttf
│   │       └── font.eot
│   │       └── font.woff
│   ├── static
│   │   └── css
│   │       └── base.css
│   ├── templates
│   └── views
```

варианты @font-face, которые пробовал

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  src: url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../../font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  src: url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Но шрифт не применяется к элементу:

```css
.element__symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  font: bold 15pt open_sansbold;
}
```

При инспектировании страницы выдает open_sansbold, но используется шрифт с засечками
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UDP. Добавил структуру проекта, на ней видно, где распологаются шрифты и базовый файл стилей.

Comment: Сообщение от IDE, что шрифт не поддерживается (font property font-family does not have). не пойму, где неправильно поключил

Comment: А путь правильно прописан к шрифту?

Comment: Тут явно с путями борода. `../../` это ниже корня свиду, туда доступа нет если конечно вы не двумя папками выше находитесь. Лучше от корня вставлять просто `/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot')`

Comment: @Vedenin добавил структуру проекта, да, тоже думал о путях и пробовал разные варианты, в вопросе указал

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev добавил структуру проекта, да, тоже думал о путях и пробовал разные варианты, в вопросе указал

Answer (score 1):

У вас ошибка в подключении шрифта, кавычки забыли:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'open_sansbold';
  src: url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.svg#open_sansbold') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.element__symbol {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  font: bold 15pt 'open_sansbold';
}
```

Comment: ничего не изменило

Comment: Тогда точно проблема в путях, `http://ваш_домен/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.eot` лежит?

Comment: не находит шрифт, для второго вариант font-face такой реквест: Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff  вроде все ок

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, шрифт подключен как normal, а используется bold-написание. Попробуйте сменить font-weight на normal у element__symbol.

Проверить подгружается ли шрифт можно во вкладке Network. Только учтите, что если шрифт не используется на странице, то и подгружаться он не будет, так что проверьте сперва то, что я написал выше.

Comment: кстати да, это тоже косяк, но не причина ошибки.

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev по первому замечанию нет

Comment: @ArtemGorlachev второе да, не находит шрифт, для второго вариант font-face такой реквест: Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8000/common/font/open-sans/OpenSans-Bold-webfont.woff