# Какие шрифты нужны из @font-face kit?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты

При получении сборки шрифтов из генератора в ней присуствует несколько каталогов для различного начертания шрифта. Например, для open-sans https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans

Например, для страницы мне нужны несколько начертаний шрифта (light, semibold, italic, regular). 
Для работы мне нужно каждый описывать отдельно через @font-face или достаточного взять один, например, reqular? а его вид регулировать параметрами font-weight и font-style? 
направьте, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нужно подключать все. Браузер не станет сам угадывать имена файлов на сервере.

Comment: тут на англоязычном stackoverflow мне сказали, подключай гугл-шрифты, работают быстрее. я усомнился в надежности и быстроте такого решения (так как зависишь от удаленного ресурса), за что отхватил минусов. что можете подсказать по этому поводу

Comment: @while1pass, а дай ссылку на вопрос.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625198/doesnt-display-the-font-you-added-via-font-face

Comment: @while1pass, задай отдельным вопросом и дай ссылку.

Comment: Он уже здесть есть http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/568860/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-font-face

Comment: @while1pass, я имел в виду вопрос про скорость

Comment: Нет, конкретно про сравнение скорости локальных и гугл-шрифтов нет. Сейчас сделаю

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45837/discussion-between-while1pass-and-qwertiy).

Comment: Готово http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569823/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B8-google-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D1%82%D0%B0

Answer (score 1):

При помощи **@font-face** вы подключаете шрифт и даете ему имя, в дальнейшем его не нужно подключать для повторного использования относительно таблицы стилей в которой вы его подключили.

Comment: Формулировка _"относительно таблицы стилей в которой вы его подключили"_ какая-то мутная и больше запутывает ответ, чем поясняет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, я знаю куда и как подключать, проблем с этим нет. вопрос в другом, в наборах есть несколько каталогов для разных начертаний (нормальный, полужирный и т.п) и соответствующие файлы стилей с фонт-фейсом. и мне стало интересно, для каждого начертания нужно включать файлы шрифтов в проект и расширять цсс новым фонтфейсом? или можно обойстись, например, одним нормальным начертанием шрифта? ведь оно отличается от жирного только параметром- font-weight: bold

Comment: * К предыдущему комментарию* Соответственно, остальные начертания получать просто добавление нужных свойств

Comment: @while1pass Не знаю про какие наборы вы говорите, но я подключал шрифт к таблице и использовал, то что мне нужно - (курсив, жирность).

Comment: https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/open-sans вот на странице при скачивание кита, в архиве для каждого начертания есть своя таблица и свой набор шрифтов