# Сравнение скорости загрузки серверного шрифта и google-шрифта

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, шрифты, google-fonts

На англоязычном стаке задавал [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625198/doesnt-display-the-font-you-added-via-font-face) о проблемах подключения шрифта через @font-face.

Один из ответов советовал, что нужно подключать гугл-шрифт - это надежный и более быстрый способ подключения шрифта.

В этом я сомневаюсь, так как мы зависим от стороннего ресурса - расстояния до него, скорости работы и доступности. Возможно, я чего-то не знаю, подскажите, пожалуйста

Comment: Лично меня категорически не устраивают любые зависимости от сторонних сервисов (в конце концов они банально не работают при отключенном интернете), поэтому я скачиваю гугл-шрифты себе)

Comment: @andreymal тут мы солидарны, но в ответе довольно взвешено все привели. остается подобрать альтернативу для шрифта, при недоступности ресурса.

Comment: баян это! уже где только не обсуждалось про мнимую недоступность гугл-серверов. яндекс - да, обваливался как-то, гугл - ни разу. распределенные сервера и тд и тп. слова чуть выше про "про отключенный интернет" сделали мой сегодняшний вечер))) автор, надеюсь пишет сайты не только для пользования внутри квартирной сети? )))

Comment: @СергейВ. спасибо за искрометный комментарий. возможно, комментатор погорячился с фразой "отключенный интернет", если мы, конечно, не рассматриваем какой-нибудь "золотой щит", но его ответ не лишен смысла. вспомнить хотя бы то как вольно гугл обращается со своими API и сервисами, от чего часто страдают разработчики. примеры навскидку - смена версии youtube API гуглом поломало некоторые сайты, у того же яндекса - прикрыли xml файл Яндекс-погоды. поэтому идея иметь локальный ресурс или резервный вариант не такая уж и глупая идея

Comment: ну так грех жаловаться - цэж все бесплатное))) вон сейчас все орут по поводу нового интерфейса яндекс-почты... )))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для начала, стандартные плюсы и минусы CDN:

- <kbd>+</kbd> Используется многими сайтами, поэтому весьма вероятно, что будет взято из кэша браузера, что позволит сэкономить на количестве запросов к серверу и объёме загружаемых данных. **[СОМНИТЕЛЬНО]:** Браузеры на основе Хромиума создают теперь отдельный кэш на каждый запрашивающий домен.
- <kbd>+</kbd> Снижает нагрузку на сервер, поскольку ресурс теперь отдаётся не им, а сторонним (в данном случае гугловским) сервером.
- <kbd>+</kbd> Позволяет увеличить число потоков одновременной загрузки. Браузеры используют ограничение - не более 8 потоков загрузки на один домен. Но CDN принадлежит другому домену, поэтому получается 8 потоков на твой сайт и ещё по 8 на каждый чужой домен.

Минусы, в основном, сводятся к зависимости от стороннего ресурса:

- <kbd>−</kbd> Если он по какой-то причине недоступен, то у тебя на сайте шрифта не будет.
  Для скриптов часто делается фоллбек.
- <kbd>−</kbd> Если CDN вдруг начнёт отдавать что-то другое, пользователи увидят результат раньше тебя. Для собственного сервера ведь ты сначала проверишь, что изменилось и только потом изменённые файлы окажутся у пользователей.
  Пример такой проблемы: [Как загрузить шрифт Roboto v15?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/657714/178988).
- <kbd>?</kbd> Теперь есть два сайта, которые можно пытаться взломать. Впрочем, не думаю. что это актуально для шрифтов, да и у гугловских серверов должна быть надёжная защита.
  Но в случае подмены скрипта все сайты, использующие его, окажутся под угрозой.
  Хотя, от этого в некоторой мере помогает перманентное кэширование - клиенты, у которых файл уже есть в кэше, на сервер за ним даже не пойдут.
- <kbd>−</kbd> Если свой сервер находится в локальной/корпоративной сети, то скорость доступа к нему выше, чем к CDN. Кроме того, с ним можно работать даже если интернет недоступен.

Теперь что касается именно шрифтов:

- <kbd>?</kbd> Гуглошрифты позволяют указать набор интересующих тебя символов, что позволит сократить объём файлов шрифта. С другой стороны, чем более хитрый набор ты укажешь, тем меньше вероятность, что нужный файл уже будет в кэше браузера.
- <kbd>+</kbd> Скорее всего, гуглошрифты уже оптимизированы под использование на веб-сайтах. Не могу сказать, как именно, но на 90% уверен, что если это возможно, то они об этом позаботились.

Comment: Для http2 третий плюс вроде не плюс, а минус

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. В качестве фоллбека, как понимаю, при недоступности ресурса мне указать альтернативный шрифт в параметре font-family? а как же быть с размером и прочими атрибутами, например, для моего основного шрифта я все подобрал, а допустим для Ариала, который пойдет на замену нужны свои стили

Comment: @andreymal, не уверен. К тому же, по http2 работают далеко не все сайты. А ещё, он же только https, т. е. если сайт работает по незащищённому соединению, то оно гарантированно не http2.

Comment: @while1pass, про фоллбек я говорил про скрипты. Как сделать фоллбек для шрифта, я не думал - тут надо разбираться.

Comment: спасибо, разберусь сам

Comment: @Qwertiy в 2016 году сайт без https и без http2 — плохой, негодный сайт :)

Answer (score 1):

Гугл шрифты используют многие сайты и поэтому есть вероятность того, что у пользователя в кеше уже хранится шрифт и при заходе на Ваш сайт он будет взят их кеша.

Если сохранять на своём сервере, то это лишний трафик и запросы.

Answer (score 0):

Еще об одном немаловажном факте забыли упомянуть Шрифты загруженные локально содержат в себе кучу ненужного хлама разные символы и прочую ненужную хрень а это лишние запросы. Google Fonts выдает чистый шрифт только то что используется на сайте остальное отсекается это тоже плюс хоть и небольшой