# Почему погрузка внешних CDN библиотек не желательна?

Tags: javascript, jquery, lib

Доброй ночи уважаемые, подскажите пожалуйста мне, молодому разработчику, почему размещение API библиотек с внешних источников через абсолютный адресс (для примера https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/core.js ) на сервере не желательно? (Про это мне написало в PageSpeed тесте)
*Лично я для себя пришел только к той идеи что cdnjs.cloudflare.com может в один прекрасный момент перестать поддерживать библиотеку.
+первый раз если у пользователя нету данной библиотеки в куки он будет грузить мою страницу чуть дольше. (Но в последующем же это должно компенсироваться?)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569831/178988