# Как загрузить шрифт Roboto v15?

Tags: google-fonts

Для загрузки всегда использовал данную ссылку: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900&subset=latin,cyrillic", но уже несколько дней наблюдаю, что шрифт Roboto 16px стал более вытянутый. Смотрю в файл css, а там фигурирует новая версия "s/roboto/v16/".

Вопрос, можно ли как-то принудительно указать, что мне нужна именно 15 версия?

Answer (score 5):

Эта проблема уже неделю обсуждается в репозитории Roboto.

https://github.com/google/roboto/issues/243 и https://github.com/google/roboto/issues/244

Говорят, что так стало "лучше", поскольку исправлена некая ошибка, которую мало кто замечал, а то, что шрифт стал выглядеть как другой шрифт - это, как говорится, "ваши проблемы" (при этом шрифт Roboto используется более чем на 10 миллионах сайтов и на многих порушил дизайн).

Единственный вариант решить этот вопрос раз и навсегда - грузить нужную версию шрифта со своего хоста, не надеясь и не рассчитывая на неконтролируемые сторонние сервисы.

Comment: Вот примерно поэтому я избегаю любых «облачных» сервисов и неконтролируемых CDN :)

Comment: @andreymal, вместо избегания зависимости дизайна размера надписей?) Хотя про CDN согласен.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну например мне субъективно новый Roboto не нравится и без учёта размера) Впрочем, я выкачал себе его давно и мне пофиг, могу поделиться если кому-то пригодится)

Comment: @labris подгрузку через googleapis.com использую, т.к. вроде под каждый браузер наиболее оптимальный вариант (размер/похожесть) отправляется. Не знаю что они там за ошибку нашли, но 16-18-20px превратились в какой-то жирненький Arial. Т.е. при адаптивности сайт сам на себя при смене размера шрифта не похож...

Comment: Ничего там не отправляется под браузер, просто перечислены URL файлов со шрифтами, и все. Поставьте шрифты к себе и все будет хорошо.

Comment: @labris специально перепроверил и разным браузерам содержимое "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900&subset=latin,cyrillic" отдаётся разное. Для IE8 одно, для Chrome Mac другое, для Chrome Windows третье. для Opera Android четвертое и т.д.

Comment: А шрифт-то один и тот же отдается, все равно.

Comment: @labris вот это не проверял. Раньше когда-то увидел, что разным браузерам разное содержимое отдаётся и подумал, что автоматом наиболее оптимальный вариант шрифта для разных ОС отдаётся. Т.к. вроде были проблемы с правильной отрисовкой на разных ОС.

Comment: Каждый браузер рендерит шрифт по-своему. И с этим никак нельзя бороться. См. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30876894/how-to-prevent-different-browsers-rendering-fonts-differently и http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082632/same-font-except-its-weight-seems-different-on-different-browsers

Comment: @labris googleapis частично с этим и борется, подгружая под разные ОС своим варианты шрифта. Например, кириллица, под Win10 Chrome выдал https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/mErvLBYg_cXG3rLvUsKT_fesZW2xOQ-xsNqO47m55DA.woff2 , а под Mac Firefox - https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v16/uYECMKoHcO9x1wdmbyHIm3-_kf6ByYO6CLYdB4HQE-Y.woff2 . Сравнил и между ними есть отличия. Только по этой причине пользуюсь именно googleapis, так бы давно всё к себе на сервер закинул.