# В чем негативные стороны использования google fonts?

Tags: оптимизация, шрифты, оптимизация-сайтов

Довольно часто встречаю в публикациях идеи подключать шрифты из облака по средствам [GoogleFonts](https://fonts.google.com/), а не использовать отдельно хранимые с сервера.

Аргументация обычно такая:

> 1. Их не надо хранить на сервере
> 2. Google хранилища будут всегда доступны если у вас есть Интернет, а нету Интернета, так зачем вам сайт
> 3. Не надо париться с этим множеством расширений ttf, otf, woff... браузер сам знает что ему тянуть

Может мне кто-то объяснить где истина? Если перечисленные мною параметры настолько хороши, то в чём же может быть негативные стороны?

Comment: Однажды Roboto обновился, его внешний вид изменился, куча дизайнов сайтов сломалась, дизайнеры люто бугуртили... так что хз-хз, я себе всё скачиваю)

Comment: Это из области, "однажды Google сервера поломаются" и все будут вынужденны пользоваться Яндексом и Yahoo. Хотелось бы болие реальные случаии

Comment: [Это абсолютно реальный уже случившийся случай](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/657738/178213)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сравнение скорости загрузки серверного шрифта и google-шрифта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/569823/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8-google-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: @andreymal, о, спасибо за пример. Ещё тогда видел его, но только сейчас добавил в свой ответ :)

Comment: Кто ещё может предложить негативых моментов, почему все не должны перейти на google шрифты?

Answer (score 1):

Самое важное тут скорость. Сайт грузится быстрее, так как шрифты подгружаются с другого сервера. Если подключать свои шрифты то это обеспечивает автономность, но опять же нагружает больше сервер. Я обычно храню локально, заказчикам сбрасываю две версии (локально + googlefonts). Ну и опять же. Не все шрифты есть на googlefonts и если нет то выбор очевиден.